# PHP/MYSQL: Login with multiple types of users

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a login page for admin and super admin in one PHP page. Currently, I do login page for admin and super admin separately but use the same database table.

Below is my current code for admin and super admin login

admin_login.php

```
<?php
include("config/config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Email']);
  $Pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Pwd']); 

  $sql = "SELECT staff.Email FROM staff WHERE Email = '$Email' AND Pwd ='$Pwd' AND staff.Role = 'admin'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count == 1) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $Email;

     header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
   }

?>
```

super_admin_login.php

```
<?php
include("config/config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Email']);
  $Pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Pwd']); 

  $sql = "SELECT staff.Email FROM staff WHERE Email = '$Email' AND Pwd ='$Pwd' AND staff.Role = 'super_admin'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count == 1) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $Email;

     header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
   }

?>
```

can anyone help me? Really appreciate

Comment: You are storing PLAIN TEXT PASSWORD, That is very bad. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: You are approaching this from slightly the wrong perspective. Every user should login through the same script. User presents a User and Password, you check they are correct and THEN you pick up the `staff.Role` to know what kind of user they are, and treat them accordingly

Comment: thanks, guys. I will change it later. but can anyone help regarding my question?

Comment: Why not remove this  `AND staff.Role = ` SQL condition  after that check for admin or user_admin then redirect accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing now is to check if there is any username and password with the specific role, why not checking username and password and after that check the role of it to redirect to correct place ?

You can merge them, **What you should do is to first check username and password and after that check the role to see if it is Admin or Super Admin to redirect to correct dashboard.**

```
    <?php
include("config/config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Email']);
  $Pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Pwd']); 

  $sql = "SELECT staff.Email,staff.Role FROM staff WHERE Email = '$Email' AND Pwd ='$Pwd'"; // Remember You do not need to check role here so you can accept both
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count == 1) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $Email;

     if($row["Role"] == "admin"){ //Check the role here
         header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");
     }else{ // If you want to be more specific you can write a else-if here too.
         header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
     }
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
   }

?>
```

***PS: NEVER STORE PLAIN PASSWORD AND USE PREPARED STATEMENTS TO PREVENT SQL INJECTION***

Comment: As a completion to this good explanation for the current problem, for the passwords matter: simple hashing of passwords might also not be sufficient (still better than plaintext though), some hash functions will eventually produce collisions. Try to read about the adding salt to your passwords: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) for a small improvement regarding the encryption. Anyway, it depends the purpose of the snippet you provided. If it is meant to be published and used ask for pro help, and even try delegating the auth matter to social connect (OAuth).

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this from slightly the wrong perspective. Every user should login through the same script. User presents a UserId (Email in your case) and Password, you check they are correct and THEN you pick up the `staff.Role` to know what kind of user they are, and treat them accordingly

> I have also changed your code to use a prepared, parameterised and bound query

```
<?php
include("config/config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    //$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Email']);
    //$Pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Pwd']); 

    $sql = "SELECT Pwd, Role 
            FROM staff 
            WHERE Email = ?";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['Email']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if ($result->num_rows == 1 )
        // this should really be using `password_verify()`
        // but as that requiesa change to the way you save the password
        // I cannot just add it here

        if ( $_POST['Pwd'] == $row['Pwd'] ){
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $Email;
            // might be useful to put the role in the session for later use as well
            $_SESSION['Role'] = $row['Role'];
            if ($row['Role'] == 'admin')
                header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");    
                exit;
            }
            if ($row['Role'] == 'super_admin')
                header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");    
                exit;
            }

        } else {
            $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

> Additional reading to change your code to use the more secure  [`password_hash()` and `pasword_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)